# How to convert Bitmap to ImageProxy in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, androidx

It seems that `androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy` is an abstract class, but I can't find any public class that can easily build an instance with `Bitmap` or `Image`.

Is there any?

Comment: Wondering the same thing! Would be very useful for creating tests of analyzers in mlkit for instance

Comment: @Gober I was gonna do the same thing.